# Technique of using volatile flag as replacement to locking

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently, I came across a `volatile` flag technique, which I may avoid from using `synchronized` or `lock`.

http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Here is one of the code example of using `volatile` flag.

**Correct Working Example**

```
Thread 1
========
// re-odering will not happen. initialize_var...
// will not move below "volatile_initialization_ready = true"
// statement.
initialize_var1();
initialize_var2();
initialize_var3();
volatile_initialization_ready = true;


Thread 2
========
if (volatile_initialization_ready) {
    use_var1();
    use_var2();
    use_var3();
}
```

However, I find out I just can't use this technique in certain situation as follow.

**Wrong Working Example**

```
Thread 1
========
volatile_going_to_destroy = true;
destroy_var1();
destroy_var2();
destroy_var3();

Thread 2
========
if (volatile_going_to_destroy) {
    return;    // ignore.
}

// But Thread 1 still able to perform destroy
// when Thread 2 halt right here. Also, re-ordering might
// happen, where destroy_var1 might move above 
// "volatile_going_to_destroy = true" statement.
use_var1();
use_var2();
use_var3();
```

I was wondering, is it possible for me to make **Wrong Working Example** work, but just using `volatile`, without using `synchronized` or `lock`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**volatile** only solves the [visibility problem](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=19). You still need [locks for synchronization](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_safety.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm like the following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm. It allows for safe variable access with only memory barriers but without locks.

Comment: The java.util.concurrent.atomic package provides classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables